# Java static error

Tags: java, static, static-methods, static-class

I'm trying to compile this program in Netbeans: [Lab1.java](http://evenovia.com/dl/Lab1.java)

And I get this error...

BF.java:27: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
return new Program(new BF().doParse(str));

I've tried everything!

Comment: Please copy/paste the relevant code snippets into your question. Also please be sure to use the "Homework" tag if this is a question about homework.

Comment: BTW: The file can't be called `Lab1.java` if you want to actually compile this program. It would have to be called `BF.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Program inner class is not declared static. What this means is that a Program instance can only live inside an enclosing instance of the outer BF class.  If you want the Program class to  exist independently, so that you can write `new BF.Program()` you have to declare it `static`.

In your program, you're creating a new instance of Program in the main method in a static context without an enclosing BF instance, which is illegal. Just add static to the program class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Change line 171 from:

```
class Program implements Node
```

to this:

```
static class Program implements Node
```

Answer (score 0):

[Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-java)